# Extracting Data from an XML Response whic is now in an XmlElement array

Tags: google-apps-script

Newbie but have been playing with this to the point where my limited knowledge fails me

Am trying to get the company name for a stock number
I call the Google Finance URL and receive an XML response.

From the XML response i want to extract the Company element and the Attribute (I hope my XML  terminology is correct)

using Debug i can see most of it but I cant understand why "thecompanyname" is not being returned.

Help appreciated code below

```
function myFunction() {

//Base URL for getting the Stock information
// http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=....


var single_quote_returntxt = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=0005").getContentText();
//Get a single stock quote for HSBC code 0005

var quoteinxmldoc = Xml.parse(single_quote_returntxt,true);
// Put the receieved xml response into XMLdocument format


var topelement = quoteinxmldoc.getElement().getElement();
//Get the top element and the next am guessing here a little 

var wantedelement = topelement.getElements();
//the element level i want

var thecompanyname =  wantedelement[3].getText();
//The company name as a string  


Browser.msgBox("End");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing the elements of the XML document incorrectly. Take a look at how it's structured, using the debugger:

[image: wantedelement]

Your `wantedelement` array contains objects, each with a `data` key. So to access the company name, you just need to do this:

```
var thecompanyname =  wantedelement[3].data;
```

And here's the result:

[image: Debugger Screen Shot]

Comment: Many thanks, now that its explained in this manner it is clear and working Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a pure GAS method and using the Logger, here is a way to see what is where...

```
function myFunction() {
var single_quote_returntxt = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=0005").getContentText();
Logger.log(single_quote_returntxt)
var quoteinxmldoc = Xml.parse(single_quote_returntxt,true);
var topelements = quoteinxmldoc.getElement().getElement().getElements();
for(var e in topelements){
  var element = topelements[e]
  var att = element.getAttributes();
    for(var a in att){Logger.log('Element '+e+' ='+element.getName().getLocalName()+' attribute :'+ att[a].getName().getLocalName()+'  :  '+att[a].getValue())}
  var wantedelement = element.getElements();
  for(var w in wantedelement){Logger.log('wantedelement '+w+' :'+wantedelement[w].getText())}
      }
}
```

Logger.log =

```
Element 0 =symbol attribute :data  :  0005
Element 1 =pretty_symbol attribute :data  :  0005
Element 2 =symbol_lookup_url attribute :data  :  /finance?client=ig&q=0005
Element 3 =company attribute :data  :  HSBC Holdings plc (Hong Kong)
Element 4 =exchange attribute :data  :  HKG
Element 5 =exchange_timezone attribute :data  :  
Element 6 =exchange_utc_offset attribute :data  :  
Element 7 =exchange_closing attribute :data  :  
Element 8 =divisor attribute :data  :  2
Element 9 =currency attribute :data  :  HKD
Element 10 =last attribute :data  :  84.55
Element 11 =high attribute :data  :  84.95
Element 12 =low attribute :data  :  84.10
Element 13 =volume attribute :data  :  17368416
Element 14 =avg_volume attribute :data  :  12414
Element 15 =market_cap attribute :data  :  1562574.91
Element 16 =open attribute :data  :  84.40
Element 17 =y_close attribute :data  :  84.15
Element 18 =change attribute :data  :  +0.40
Element 19 =perc_change attribute :data  :  0.48
Element 20 =delay attribute :data  :  15
Element 21 =trade_timestamp attribute :data  :  5 hours ago
Element 22 =trade_date_utc attribute :data  :  20130319
Element 23 =trade_time_utc attribute :data  :  075959
Element 24 =current_date_utc attribute :data  :  20130319
Element 25 =current_time_utc attribute :data  :  132906
Element 26 =symbol_url attribute :data  :  /finance?client=ig&q=0005
Element 27 =chart_url attribute :data  :  /finance/chart?q=HKG:0005&tlf=12
Element 28 =disclaimer_url attribute :data  :  /help/stock_disclaimer.html
Element 29 =ecn_url attribute :data  :  
Element 30 =isld_last attribute :data  :  
Element 31 =isld_trade_date_utc attribute :data  :  
Element 32 =isld_trade_time_utc attribute :data  :  
Element 33 =brut_last attribute :data  :  
Element 34 =brut_trade_date_utc attribute :data  :  
Element 35 =brut_trade_time_utc attribute :data  :  
Element 36 =daylight_savings attribute :data  :  true
```

but Mogsdad method is cleaner and faster... no doubt about that ;-)

Comment: Hi am going to work through this over the weekend, looks like a good learning exercise Thanks